# asp.net connection open and close

Tags: asp.net

Let say i have one asp.net application that is having some page that uses the connection continuesly.....

i have open the connection in class file in construscter ......

and i m accessing it using the object of the class....when ever database operation are required...

in start the application is running fine....but after some operation with database in datagrid(ex. sorting,paging,other).... it's gets slow...and again start working after some time....

do you guys have any solution or any suggession for that.....

i have used the connection in following way....

```
public class student_operation
{
    public SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    public SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
    public DataSet rs = new DataSet();
    public DataSet rs1 = new DataSet();

    public student_operation()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        try
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cn.Close();
                cn.Open();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are opening AND closing your connection. Don't worry about "pooling" the connection. .Net will handle that for you automatically. Just open the connection, do your work and close the connection (even if that's done in the static part).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are closing your connection.  I would implement IDisposable and clean everything up there.  Then you can access your class in a using statement.